# Sending an Entity on email using Mailer ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, email, mailer

Trying to develop an app where when a User applies for an appointment, they get email confirmation that the appointment has been received with their details in the email. I've got a linq query( after the appointment is created) to get their details from the database. I've debugged the app, and the details are going through to the mailer method. However, I get a blank email. Is it something to do with the ViewBag.Data?

Here's where I send the details:

```
 var app = (from a in db.Appointments
                where appointments.AppointmentId == a.AppointmentId
                   select a).FirstOrDefault()

                UserMailer.AppointmentDetails(app).Send();
```

My mailer method:

```
public virtual MvcMailMessage AppointmentDetails(Appointments appointment)
    {
        ViewBag.Data = appointment;
        return Populate(x =>
        {
            x.Subject = "Appointment Detail";
            x.ViewName = "AppointmentDetails";
            x.To.Add(appointment.ApplicantEmail);
        });
    }
```

Finally the view for the email:

```
    Appointment Details @ViewBag.Data:<br />
Welcome to the  App and enjoy your time!<br />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it, I needed to set up these in the mailer:

```
ViewBag.Details = appointment.DetailsOfAppointment;
        ViewBag.Date = appointment.DateOfAppointment;
        ViewBag.Room = appointment.RoomType;
```

Then assign them in my view